# request for member ‘write’ in ‘chol_out_data’, which is of non-class type

Tags: c++, systemc

My cholesky.cpp file:

```
#include "chol.h"
#include <math.h>

//Main Thread

void chol::chol_main () {
    // Variable declaration
    sc_fixed<16,10, SC_TRN, SC_WRAP> chol_output[3][3];
    sc_fixed<16,10, SC_TRN, SC_WRAP> chol_in[3][3];
    int n=3;

    //Main Thread
    while (true) {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<=i; j++){
                chol_in[i][j] = chol_in_data[i][j].read();
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<=i; j++){
            sc_fixed<16,10, SC_TRN, SC_WRAP> sum = 0;
            for (int k=0; k<j; k++){
                sum += chol_output[i][k] * chol_output[j][k];
            }

            if (i==j){
                chol_output[i][i] = sqrt(chol_in[i][i] - sum) ;
            }else{
                chol_ouput[i][j] = 1.0 / chol_ouput[j][j] * (chol_in[i][j] - sum);
            }
        }
    }

    chol_out_data.write(chol_output);   
}
```

The header file for this chol.h:

```
#ifndef CHOL
#define CHOL
#define SC_INCLUDE_FX
#include "define.h"

SC_MODULE (chol) {
public:
   // Inputs
   sc_in_clk clk;
   sc_in <bool> rst;
   sc_in <sc_fixed<16,10, SC_TRN, SC_WRAP> > chol_in_data[3][3] ;

   // Output
   sc_out <sc_fixed<16,10, SC_TRN, SC_WRAP> > chol_out_data[3][3] ;

   /* F */
   void chol_main ( void );

   // Constructor
   SC_CTOR (chol) {
       SC_CTHREAD (chol_main, clk.pos());
       reset_signal_is(rst, false) ;
       sensitive << clk.pos();
   }

   // Destructor
   ~chol() {}
};

#endif
```

Output:

```
g++  -O1 -I"/home/mahesh/systemc/systemc-2.3.1a/include" -I"." -c cholesky.cpp -o cholesky.o
    cholesky.cpp: In member function ‘void chol::chol_main()’:
    cholesky.cpp:47:5: error: ‘chol_ouput’ was not declared in this scope
         chol_ouput[i][j] = 1.0 / chol_ouput[j][j] * (chol_in[i][j] - sum);
         ^


    cholesky.cpp:54:17: error: request for member ‘write’ in ‘chol_out_data’, which is of non-class type ‘sc_core::sc_out<sc_dt::sc_fixed<16, 10, (sc_dt::sc_q_mode)5u, (sc_dt::sc_o_mode)3u> > [3][3]’
       chol_out_data.write     (chol_output);                                       
                     ^

    Makefile:90: recipe for target 'cholesky.o' failed
    make: *** [cholesky.o] Error 1
```

I am performing a matrix decomposition and I am writing the output of the 2D array of the cholesky module to the signal port which is connected to the cholesky testbench module.

I have declared the chol_output variable within the scope; still, I get the same error that it is out of scope. Also, it says that the 'write' is of non class type.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `chol_ouput` is not `chol_output` !! and an array has no "write" method

Comment: Then How will i write my values to the output port?

Answer (score 1):

For the first error, you just misspelled `chol_output` as `chol_ouput`.

The second error is just what it says: `chol_out_data` is not a class object, so you can't use `.` on it.  It's an array of array of class objects.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my first error. For the second thing in systemC to write in an output port we have to use '.' operator. I have declared chol_out_data as my output port and I am trying write my values to the output port .

Now my problem is I am not able to write an array variable in my output port it throws the following error










error: invalid conversion from ‘sc_dt::sc_fixed<16, 10, (sc_dt::sc_q_mode)5u, (sc_dt::sc_o_mode)3u> (*)[3]’ to ‘sc_dt::uint64 {aka long long unsigned int}’ [-fpermissive]
   chol_out_data[i][j].write (chol_output);